# Переменная и children

Tags: jquery

Здравствуйте.
Не могу никак с переменной data получить children блок.
Просьба подсказать.
Спасибо.

```
$.get("/page"+thisPageNum+"/", function(data){
    var result=data.children('.box-poster').html();
    $('#mainCat').html(result);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот вам третий вариант, если версия библиотеки у вас не древняя (1.8.+).

```
$.get("/page"+thisPageNum+"/", function(data) {
    var elems = $.parseHTML(data);
    $('#mainCat').html($(elems).find('.box-poster'));
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте так.

```
$.get("/page"+thisPageNum+"/", function(data) {
    var result = $(data).find('.box-poster').html();
    $('#mainCat').html(result);
});
```

Comment: С $(data) перестает работать, если $('data') то работае, но мне не надо <data>
Не пойму в чем проблема. Уже и ajax() и load() пробовал.

Comment: А что у вас отдает скрипт? Чему равна переменная `data`?

Comment: data ето html код страницы загрузки.

Comment: Ну, так вам два правильных ответа дали. Определитесь с селектором, чтоб получить нужные элементы и всё.

Answer (score 2):

Я так понял у вас в переменной data приходит html код? 
Ну так сначала преобразуйте его в jQuery объект:

```
$.get("/page"+thisPageNum+"/", function(data){
    var result= $(data).children('.box-poster').html();
    $('#mainCat').html(result);
});
```